# "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create') when using Sequelize's User.create() method"

Tags: import, sequelize.js, export, typeerror

I'm facing a peculiar issue with my `Node.js` application using `Sequelize`. When I run my code locally, everything works smoothly without any errors. However, when I send a POST request using `Thunder` (a tool for sending HTTP requests), the server crashes, and I receive the following error message: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')`.

It seems that the problem occurs specifically when I attempt to use Sequelize's User.create() method to create a new user.

I've thoroughly checked my code, including the `Sequelize` model definition and the way I'm importing the User model, but I'm unable to pinpoint the cause of the issue.

Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this problem would be highly appreciated.

Comment: At least show the model module and how you import it in the controller module